# float to double and int to long conversions

Tags: java

when the float is automatically taken as double, int should be considered as long right?? but int is being considered as int. can anyone explain this behaviour.

```
public class Test
{
void met (int x){
System.out.println("int called");

}

void met (long x){
System.out.println("long called");

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t= new Test();
    t.met(10);
}

}
Output : int is called.
******************************************************************************************
public class Test
{
void met (float x){
System.out.println("float called");

}

void met (double x){
System.out.println("double called");

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t= new Test();
    t.met(10.0);
}

}

output : double called.
```

Comment: False premise: 10.0 is a `double`, not a `float`. And obviously, if an overload with the exact type is available, that will be chosen.

Comment: For a float you would need `(float) 10` or `10f`. `10.0` is a *double*.

Comment: Take a look at [Java Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), especially at literals.

Comment: http://ideone.com/uIxR7M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the default type for a numeric value is int. If you want it to be considered a long, it should be suffixed with l or L:

```
long l = 10l;
```

For floating values, the default type is double. If you want a float, it should be suffixed with f or F:

```
float f = 10.0f;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an
>   ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can
>   optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d (§4.2.3).

and

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

To change type you could call the methods with `10.0F` and `10L` respectivly

To further add content, the default type is the type that is most commonly used (?)